# Converting English events to Set Theory Notation using Operators

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Just having a little bit of a hard time converting these 3 English statements into proper set-theory notation. They are just very ambigious.

A, B, C, D are events in sample space S. Express the events (described in English) using the operators $\cup , \cap,$ \ , and complement.

1. A occurs but not both B and C
2. Exactly three of the events occur, but if B is in the trio then C is not, AND vice-versa.
3. Exactly one of A,B,C occur, as well as D

I think I got 1, not too sure, here is my answer:

$ A \cap (B \cap C)^\complement $

Comment: try number 1 again :)

Comment: Would number one be $A \cap (B \cap C)^\complement$

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding these are the answers that I got, could someone please verify them and / or correct them:

1. $ A \cap ( B \cap C)^c $
2. $ ABD \cup ACD $
3. $ D \cap (A \cup B \cup C ) $

Comment: 2 and 3 are wrong: $X \cup Y$ means **at least** one of $X, Y$ occurs, not **exactly** one of them.